# Increase Y position on MouseButtonDown?

Tags: c#, unity

How can I increase the altitude of a GameObject as long as `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` is activated? "The longer the button is pressed the higher the GameObject goes." **I also want to show the gained altitude.** And when the gained altitude has reached a specfic value, stop the movement.
How can I do this?

Here's non-working a pseudo code, so you can understand better:

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
         smoothly increase y position (lerp maybe?)// transform.position.y + 1?
         Debug.Log(gainedHeight)
         if(gainedHeight == 10)
            {
                 stop movement and stay at reached position //transform.position.y + 0?
            }
   }
```

Comment: Do you want it to fall down once the button is released?

Comment: I don't know what is the most absurd thing about this question: 1) that it is titled "GameObject issues" but just asks how to merely change the position of a GameObject; 2) that it asks something like that, showing that obviously no search effort at all was attempted before asking (the answer is in the very first steps of any basic tutorial on whatever system the OP uses - which was not informed btw); 3) that it is tagged only as "post-processing" - something that has nothing to do with the question; 4) that it is still open and active.

Comment: @MAnd It used to be a proper question until the author edited it to replace it with a completely pointless one. He tends to do that all the time for some reason.

Comment: @Philipp Many thanks for having the patience to save the question, by recovering its original state. Now it looks like a very basic question that could be easily solved in about 10 ms by google searching, but still a question nevertheless (and with correct tagging). Much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The longer the button is pressed the higher the GameObject goes."

---

**Here is how Input button returns functions:**

**A** = Input.GetMouseButtonDown

**B** = Input.GetMouseButton

**C** = Input.GetMouseButtonUp

1. Frame 1 (**Not pressed yet**): All three are false.
2. Frame 2 (**Pressed**): Only A is true.
3. Frame 3 (**Holding**): Only B is true.
4. Frame 4 (**Relase**): Only C is true.
5. Frame 5 (**After relase**): All three are false.

---

**To sum up:**

You need to use ***GetMouseButton***, not ***GetMouseButtonDown***.

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform.Translate` multiplying the direction by `Time.deltaTime` ensures smoother movement.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
       currentHeight=transform.position.y;
       gainedHeight=currentheight-initialHeight;
        if(gainedheight<10)
           transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime); 

   }
```

Edit: added code to measure gainedheight.

```
float initialHeight,currentheight,gainedHeight;

void Start()
{
   initialHeight= transform.position.y;
}
```

Comment: @TheGameChanger I have edited my answer to take into account height gain.

Comment: @TheGameChanger  yes. That's right

Comment: Because I copy pasted your code :) I was trying more to show the `gainedHeight<10` condition